# Status bar in webbrowser

Tags: c#, statusbar, browser

Am looking an option on how to add status bar and show the same for webbrowser control, any thoughts on that.

When i type sites with https: on a texbox above webbrowser i am supposed to show the ssl secure icon on status bar.

Please reply.

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

To show the padlock icon, handle the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event and show the icon if `browser.Url.Scheme == "https"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [StatusTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.statustextchanged.aspx) event and check the [StatusText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.statustext.aspx) property.

You can add a StatusStrip control and a StusStripLabel to your form, then set the StatusStripLabel's `Text` property to your WebBrowser's `StatusText` property in the `StatusTextChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i can't find the statusTextchanged event for webbrowser, pls. help.

Comment: Are you using the WinForms `WebBrowser` control or COM Interop?

Comment: The event does exist; you can see its documentation on MSDN by following the link in my answer. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.statustextchanged.aspx)

Comment: Thanks again, but i am not able to create StatusTextChanged event, i used  ProgressChanged event i 

 toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = webBrowser.StatusText;

But this show the text, but am supposed to show the SSL secure sign in symbol, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx demonstrates the steps required to handle unmanaged webbroweser events